# ajv@7.2.4 - Error: strict mode: unknown keyword: "unevaluatedProperties" -

Tags: typescript, ajv

I expect the ajv keyword a `unevaluatedProperties` to be defined and working in ajv version 7.2.4, however I get the error message in the title.

Here is the npm version listing:

```
$ npm list ajv
tscapi@0.0.1 /mnt/common/github/tscapi
├── ajv@7.2.4 
└─┬ eslint@7.24.0
  ├─┬ @eslint/eslintrc@0.4.0
  │ └── ajv@6.12.6 
  ├── ajv@6.12.6 
  └─┬ table@6.2.0
    └── ajv@8.1.0
```

Here is the code that gives the error:

```
import * as ajv from 'ajv';

const schemas = [
  {
    $id: 'schemas.json#/1',
    anyOf: [{$ref: 'schemas.json#/2'}, {$ref: 'schemas.json#/3'}],
  },
  {
    $id: 'schemas.json#/2',
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      a: {type: 'string'},
    },
    required: ['a'],
    unevaluatedProperties: true,
  },
  {
    $id: 'schemas.json#/3',
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      b: {type: 'string'},
    },
    required: ['b'],
    unevaluatedProperties: true,
  },
  {
    $id: 'schemas.json#/4',
    type: 'object',
    allOf: [{$ref: 'schemas.json#/2'}, {$ref: 'schemas.json#/3'}],
    unevaluatedProperties: false,
  },
];

const validators = new ajv.default({schemas: schemas});
{
  const validate = validators.getSchema('schemas.json#/1')!;
  validate({a: 'hello'});
  if (validate.errors) throw new Error(validate.errors[0].message);
  console.log('ok 1');
}
{
  const validate = validators.getSchema('schemas.json#/4')!;
  validate({a: 'hello', b: 'hello'});
  if (validate.errors) throw new Error(validate.errors[0].message);
  console.log('ok 2');
}
```

In the file `node_modules/ajv/README.md` the following text is found, which shows that `unevaluatedProperties` should not be unknown in this version of ajv.

```
## Using version 7

Ajv version 7 has these new features:
...
- support of JSON Schema draft-2019-09 features: [`unevaluatedProperties`](./docs/json-schema.md#unevaluatedproperties) and [`unevaluatedItems`](./docs/json-schema.md#unevaluateditems), [dynamic recursive references](./docs/guide/combining-schemas.md#extending-recursive-schemas) and other [additional keywords](./docs/json-schema.md#json-schema-draft-2019-09).
...
```

I've also tried changing one line in the code

```
const validators = new ajv.default({schemas: schemas});
```

to

```
const opts = {next:true,unevaluated:true}
const validators = new ajv.default(opts).addSchema(schemas);
```

but still no luck.

What do I need to do to enable `unevaluatedProperties`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It requires explicitly loading the newer specs via

```
import Ajv2019 from "ajv/dist/2019"
const ajv = new Ajv2019()
```

as stated on either of these man pages:

- [draft-2019-09-and-draft-2012-12](https://ajv.js.org/guide/schema-language.html#draft-2019-09-and-draft-2012-12)
- [draft-2019-09](https://ajv.js.org/json-schema.html#draft-2019-09)